# Axis2 Hello World - cannot find symbol setParam0

Tags: tomcat, apache-axis

i'm trying to develop a simple Hello World web service using Axis2 v1.5, Tomcat6 and Java 1.6, according to the following [tutorial](http://wso2.org/node/95).

However, i'm getting an error in the client-side code compilation:

```
javac -extdirs C:\\axis2-1.5 org/apache/axis2/*.java  -d temp/
```

returns

```
code\src\org\apache\ws\axis2\Client.java:13: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method setParam0(java.lang.String)
location: class org.apache.axis2.TempStub.Echo
        request.setParam0("Hello world");
```

as you can see, i've made a couple of changes to the original tutorial, however, even after following the instructions exactly i still get the same error.

I also tried using an older version of Java with the -source 1.3 and -target 1.3 parameters for javac, but the issue remains.

Any ideas?
For a simple tutorial, this crap has given me a lotta headaches...

Cheers and thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial has a typo, it should be setValue, not setParam0, as in:

```
        HelloWorldStub.Echo request = new HelloWorldStub.Echo();
        request.setValue("My Parameter Value");
```

Answer (score 1):

I have also been trying to get this to work and by using jd-gui or jad I found that in the temp dir the `SimpleServiceStub$Echo` class has this method:

```
public void setArgs0(String paramString)
{
    if (paramString != null)
    {
        this.localArgs0Tracker = true;
    }
    else this.localArgs0Tracker = true;

    this.localArgs0 = paramString;
}
```

Based upon this in your `Client.java` you should use `setArgs0("hello world");`

Answer (score 0):

Use this statement: `request.setArgs0("Hello World");`

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Mark, that's a tutorial typo. The tutorial ws method was:

```
public String echo(String value) {
    return value;
}
```

so the associated client instruction should be:
request.setValue("My Parameter Value");

Basically, if the web service method was:

```
public String echo(String whatever) {
    return whatever;
}
```

the associated client call would be:
request.setWhatever("My Parameter Value");